# How to insert sentences into training data which has 2 words, 3 words 4 and 5 etc into training data?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, pytorch, nlp

I have a set of sentences which each contain 2 words, 3 words, 4 words, 5 words etc. When I am trying to give the training data only the first two words in a sentence it is not accepting it. It is showing given 4 expected 2. How do you deal with this? Said another way, how do you to insert each and every sentence into the training data. I am trying to predict the next word.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.autograd import Variable

dtype = torch.FloatTensor

sentences = [ "i like dog", "i love coffee", "i hate milk", "i love football", "hi im great", "i love watching football", "i don't eat chicken"]

word_list = " ".join(sentences).split()
word_list = list(set(word_list))
word_dict = {w: i for i, w in enumerate(word_list)}
number_dict = {i: w for i, w in enumerate(word_list)}
n_class = len(word_dict) # number of Vocabulary

# NNLM Parameter
n_step = 2 # n-1 in paper
n_hidden = 2 # h in paper
m = 2 # m in paper

def make_batch(sentences):
    input_batch = []
    target_batch = []

for sen in sentences:
    word = sen.split()
    input = [word_dict[n] for n in word[:-1]]
    target = word_dict[word[-1]]

    input_batch.append(input)
    target_batch.append(target)

return input_batch, target_batch

# Model
class NNLM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NNLM, self).__init__()
        self.C = nn.Embedding(n_class, m)
        self.H = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(n_step * m, n_hidden).type(dtype))
        self.W = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(n_step * m, n_class).type(dtype))
        self.d = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(n_hidden).type(dtype))
        self.U = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(n_hidden, n_class).type(dtype))
        self.b = nn.Parameter(torch.randn(n_class).type(dtype))

    def forward(self, X):
        X = self.C(X)
        X = X.view(-1, n_step * m) # [batch_size, n_step * n_class]
        tanh = torch.tanh(self.d + torch.mm(X, self.H)) # [batch_size, n_hidden]
        output = self.b + torch.mm(X, self.W) + torch.mm(tanh, self.U) # [batch_size, n_class]
        return output

model = NNLM()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

input_batch, target_batch = make_batch(sentences)
input_batch = Variable(torch.LongTensor(input_batch))
target_batch = Variable(torch.LongTensor(target_batch))

# Training
for epoch in range(5000):

optimizer.zero_grad()
output = model(input_batch)

# output : [batch_size, n_class], target_batch : [batch_size] (LongTensor, not one-hot)
loss = criterion(output, target_batch)
if (epoch + 1)%1000 == 0:
    print('Epoch:', '%04d' % (epoch + 1), 'cost =', '{:.6f}'.format(loss))

loss.backward()
optimizer.step()

# Predict
predict = model(input_batch).data.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]

# Test
print([sen.split()[:2] for sen in sentences], '->', [number_dict[n.item()] for n in predict.squeeze()])

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-65fcd35f0145> in <module>()
      3 
      4 input_batch, target_batch = make_batch(sentences)
----> 5 input_batch = Variable(torch.LongTensor(input_batch))
      6 target_batch = Variable(torch.LongTensor(target_batch))

ValueError: expected sequence of length 2 at dim 1 (got 3)
```

Comment: What data structure do you use for the data? How does the model look like? Can you share some code?

Comment: In addition to Jindrich's comment, can you please edit your post to also include the context behind the problem, which might help us to understand what exactly you are trying to solve?

Comment: I edited and uploaded the code above

Comment: I've added extra sentences in sentences list which has 4 words, 5 words etc